# PostgreSQL: Join tables while satisfying multiple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sorry for the weird title, I didn't know how to summarize my question. If you have a better idea, let me know and I'll update it.

Suppose I have a database scheme containing table fro both students and classes. I also have a third table connecting the first two, so I know which student attends which classes. This third connection table only contains two foreign keys, the student id and the class id.

I know how get a list of all classes attended by a single student or hot to get all students in a single class.
My question, however, is, how do I get all the students who attend ALL of the classes A, B, C and D and not just one of them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for me it sounds like "relational division". I guess you can try something like SELECT student_id FROM Your_Link_Table GROUP BY student_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT class_id)=4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select student_id
from student_classes sc
where class_id in (A, B, C, D)
group by student_id
having count(*) = 4;
```